# Most keystrokes on my Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic Keyboard are ignored

Tags: keyboard, usb, bluetooth

I am trying to get a Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic keyboard to work with my MacBook Pro and while I found a couple of posts on similar issues, none of the suggested solutions worked for me, so I am posting this, hoping someone has a fresh suggestion:

### Problem

My keyboard is skipping a lot of keys. I.e. some of the keystrokes do not appear in my editor/browser. Also moving the complementary mouse (connected to the same dongle) makes very sluggish moves on screen. It affects all keys. Occasionally, it starts working well for a couple of minutes and lagging usually starts when switching apps e.g. if I switch from OneNote to Firefox.

### Setup

- MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020, Four Thunderbolt 3 ports) macOS 10.15.7
- Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic Mouse & Keyboard. They are wireless and connect to a Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v9.0
- To connect the transceiver I use a 4x USB 2.0 to USB-C hub.
- An additional wired mouse plugged into the hub

### Troubleshooting so far

Following other posts, I tried the following on my mac:

- turning it off and on again
- turning bluetooth off on the macbook
- disable handoff for icloud devices
- disable slow keys and sticky keys.
- use different usb ports (both usb c ports on the mac and usb ports on the hub
- run `sudo fs_usage | grep -v 0.00` to see if there is any kernel throttling happening.
- disabled mouse keys

To rule out any issues with the usb dongle/hub or wireless signal jamming, I plugged the usb dongle into my Huwai MateBook (running Ubuntu), while I kept the MacBook running next to it. The keyboard works perfectly well on the other laptop.

Comment: Could you be specific about the missing keys?  If it is 789uiojkl, that is a simple fix in accessibility preferences (turn OFF Mouse Keys).

Comment: thanks for the input. it is definitely including e, t and space key and mouse keys is off. I update the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Same issue here, across a range of MacBooks (2017, 2020, 2021). The keyboard would intermittently skip keystrokes when the keyboard USB transceiver is connected via a USB hub (e.g. anker premium usb-c hub, choetech 7-in-1 usb-c hub).

It's not a complete solution, but the problem does *not* occur when the keyboard transceiver is connected directly to the MacBook (on older models pre usb-c), or via the official simple Apple usb-c to usb adapter, model A1632 (I have not tested the AV multiport one): https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ1M2AM/A/usb-c-to-usb-adapter

Comment: thanks for the suggestion!, could you specify which original adapter you have tested? I.e. the Apple USB-C Digital AV Multiport or the simple USB-C to usb adapter?

Comment: I switched to a belkin multimedia hub and it works as well. Thanks for the suggestion. I tried two hubs before that both had the issue.

Comment: edited original answer to indicate which adapter i tested

Comment: @BenjaminSchwetz could you share the very model of the belkin hub you tried? i'd be interested in trying it out.

Comment: this guy: https://www.belkin.com/us/docks-hubs/usb-c-docks/usb-c-multimedia-hub/p/p-f4u092/

Comment: I had the same issue, tried many things.  Long story short, you need a usb 2 hub with some special property -- I used the [amazon basics usb 2.0 hub](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B003M0NURK/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1) and my problems never came back :D

Comment: BTW what lead me to this was finding some blog where an engineer looked into the issue in depth.  Old versions of MacOS/OSX didn't cause the problem and they determined it had something to do with some change to the timing used for USB ports (sorry if that makes no sense, the explanation was a bit over my head).

Answer (score 1):

Something I've noticed is that if I put either of my phones down on the desk close to the receiver then it starts to drop keystrokes immediately. Sometimes a phone can be between the two with no apparentl problems, but there's definitely immediate interference if I put the phone right by the receiver and I can reproduce that with ease.

Answer (score 0):

I purchased a USB-C to USB-A from Apple that is A1632 and my sculpt works fine now...
I had a J5create USB hub where I had the same issue mentioned above...

Comment: How does this answer differ from the answer already provided?  It looks like you're just verifying the answer given works for you.